# Repeated error "Pyimage[number] does not exist"

Tags: python, image, tkinter, customtkinter

I keep getting the error mentioned in the title when I have multiple tkinter/customtkinter windows open at the same time that both have images in them. I have created an example environment similar to my original for example:

```
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
import tkinter as tk
import customtkinter

class Form1(customtkinter.CTk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.geometry(f"{950}x{560}")

        eg_image = Image.open("Example1.png")
        eg_image = eg_image.resize((200,200), Image.ANTIALIAS)
        eg_image.self = ImageTk.PhotoImage(eg_image)
        eg_image_label = customtkinter.CTkLabel(self, image=eg_image.self, text="")
        eg_image_label.place(relx=0.5,rely=0.5, anchor="c")

        def openForm2():
            app = Form2()
            app.mainloop()

        next_button = customtkinter.CTkButton(self, text="Next", command=openForm2)
        next_button.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.9, anchor="c")    

class Form2(customtkinter.CTk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.geometry(f"{950}x{560}")

        eg_image2 = Image.open("Example2.png")
        eg_image2 = eg_image2.resize((200,200), Image.ANTIALIAS)
        eg_image2.self = ImageTk.PhotoImage(eg_image2)
        eg_image2_label = customtkinter.CTkLabel(self, image=eg_image2.self,text="")
        eg_image2_label.place(relx=0.5,rely=0.5, anchor="c")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = Form1()
    app.mainloop()
```

I have read somewhere about it being to do with "garbage collection" but I am not sure what this means or how to prevent it.

Comment: It is because you have multiple instances of `customtkinter.CTk` (inherited from `tkinter.Tk`).  Use `customtkinter.CTkToplevel` instead for `Form2`.